# how can I refuse “save as” in winword by api hook

Tags: c++, api-hook

When winword process open a file and want to execute  “save as” operation ，I want to refuse  “save as” operation if the file will be saved to another directory。 
i want to use C++ by api hook，how can I do？

Comment: The question is flawed. You hook a specific function call in an API, but this question is about disabling a particular application behavior. There is zero reason to believe that this behavior coincides with any API function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, if you want to hook an external process, you need to get into this process's address space first e.g (*dll injection*). Then you need to know precisely which API function this process uses to perform such task as saving a file to be able to hook a correct one.
After all of these steps, I suggest to use [detours](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours) to hook API functions. for example:

```
typedef void savefunc_t(const char *fn); // api function prototype
savefunc_t *original_savefunc;

void savefunc_hook(const char *fn)
{
    if(strstr(fn, "dir"))   // check path and deny if otherwise execute original func
        return;
    original_savefunc(fn);
}

DetourFunction(DesiredFunctionPointer, savefunc_hook);
```

Comment: i do not want to know how to api hook， i want to know how to refuse save as operation by api hook

Comment: @qin.feng You need to hook the function first, and then deny the save from the hook.

Comment: Which hook？i do not know which  api  that i need to hook

Comment: Can you make it more detailed?

Comment: @qin.feng You need to find out which API is used to hook it, added simple example